# Using CLT (in the 'reverse' way)

Tags: probability

I have following problem to solve:

> We are throwing a dice and we end throwing when sum of the numbers on dices are $>= 300$.
>   What is the probability, that we have thrown 80 or more times?

I think I should use CLT. I don't have any problem to calculate distribution of $S_n$ (which represents probabilities of sum of the numbers after $n$ throws of dice). However, I have no idea what I should do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want the probability that if we throw the die $79$ times, the sum is $\le 299$.

For $1\le i\le 79$, let $X_i$ be the number thrown on the $i$-th toss, and let $Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{79}$. Then $Y$ is a sum of a medium-sized number of independent identically distributed "nice" random variables with known mean and variance. Probably approximating by a suitable normal $W$, particularly if we find the probability that $W\le 299.5$, will give a decent approximation to $\Pr(Y\le 299)$.

Comment: You are welcome.